# reason for using a period to call a div class and then calling it later you dont use a period?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for the sake of sanity, im wondering why when calling a div class in jquery you use a period, for example

```
var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
```

yet when i call it later in an event handler it needs to have no period otherwise it breaks the code

```
currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
```

I was just wondering why there was inconsistency here, thanks in advance.

Comment: One is a selector, the period means it's a class. The other is explicitly removing a class, so the period would be redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One is in jQuery selector format (like a CSS query). The prefix of `.` just means a class name follows (same as in CSS).
- The other is just the name of a *class* to remove, so having a class selector would be both redundant and slower as the code knows it is a class name bveing passed.

It is no different to having

```
<div class="someclass">
```

and css of

```
.someclass{
    color: blue;
}
```

Where you have no problem with the syntax being different :)

Answer (score 0):

`.removeClass` receives the class name as the parameter, and class names should not have `.` by convention:

However, `.` is used for class selectors. In your selector you have to have `.` to tell jquery that you are trying to select items with certain class: `$('.myclassname')`

For example, you would use `#` to tell jquery that you are looking for an element with a certain id: `$('#myElementId')`

Answer (score 0):

The `$('.active-slide')` is a pointer to your element.  This pointer will see non-period names as the actual name of the element like div, input.  The period tells it to work with everything that has that class and # will tell it to look for a specific id.  When you call removeClass, you are explicitly removing a class so no need to use the . to say it is a class, as it is implied.